How to correctly convert RMS to dB using UMIK-1?
So, I want to calculate dB SPL using signal from my digital microphone. I have UMIK-1 with next characteristics:

USB Audio Class :USB Audio class 1.0, Driverless interface for Windows, Mac & Linux

Connector : miniUSB connector (v1 / Before Jan 2021), USB Type C connector (v2 / After Jan 2021), Unique microphone calibration

Calibration File : .txt file referenced to the Serial Number Includes on axisFrequency, Amplitude / Sensitivity drift

Resolution & Sample rate : 24bit ADC @ 48kHz

Max SPL for 1 % TDH @ 1kHz : 133 dB SPL @OdB gain setting

Output noise level at max IGPA : -74dBFS

I have calibration file like this:
Sens Factor =-2.082dB, SERNO: 7943342"
10.054 -4.9944
10.179 -4.8272
10.306 -4.6632
10.434 -4.5024
10.564 -4.3447
10.696 -4.1902
10.829 -4.0388
10.964 -3.8904
11.1 -3.7451
11.238 -3.6027
11.378 -3.4634
11.52 -3.3269
11.663 -3.193
...
20016.816 1.5876

For db SPL calculation I use formula:
SPL = 20 * np.log10(rms) + 94 + 24 + SENS_FACTOR + 6

If I put on a calibrator with a level of 94 dB at 1 kHz, then this formula shows me about 94 dB, which is good. But at the same time, in a fairly quiet room, according to my formula, dB SPL does not fall below 50-60 dB. What's the problem?

It looks like the microphone as a max SPL of 133 dBSPL and a noise floor of 74 dB below this, which means that the noise floor of the microphone is in the 50 to 60 dBSPL range.
If you want to go below this, you need a different microphone (higher sensitivity, lower max SPL and/or higher dynamic range).
